# Edit content of export menu in yii2

Tags: yii2

I use export menu on my yii2 project. I download it from demos.krajee.com. I have been success to use it, but I want to edit content like in pdf, so it have title/header or footer or page number. How to make it?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways to do that. 
For example you can set it as default setting in

```
Yii::$container->set('kartik\grid\GridView', [
    'summary' => "Showing {begin} - {end} from {totalCount} records",
'captionOptions' => ['style' => 'font-size:0em;'],
'panel' => [
    'heading' => false,
    'before' => '{summary}',
    'after' => '{pager}',
    'footer' => false,
],
'hover' => true,
'toolbar' => [
    '{export}',
    '{toggleData}',
],
'export' =>[
    'showConfirmAlert' => false,
],
'exportConfig' => [
    kartik\grid\GridView::PDF => [
        'label' => 'Save as PDF',
        'config' => [
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader' => ['Header'],
                'SetFooter' => ['Footer whatever: ' . strftime("%c") . '||Page {PAGENO}'],
            ]
        ],
    ],
],
```

...

Or pass the settings individually to each widget in every view.

You can use methods in wrapper http://demos.krajee.com/mpdf#settings (look for methods) or directly from mpdf class if you need something more complicated.